# Standard image for the Android back\up button

Tags: android, back-button

Android UI guidelines http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html
provide a back button image download but the button appears to be a bit different from the one used in the action bar. The stencil for the action bar "back/up" is not available in the Android stencils. Does anyone know if there is standard "back/up" button resource or each app is responsible for creating it's own (opens door for less consistency)? Or does the back button comes automatically with action bar?

[image]

[image]

Comment: FYI, it's not "back/up", it's just Up.

Comment: Icon/Symbol questions are generally off-topic, per the [FAQ](http://ux.stackexchange.com/faq#im-having-trouble-coming-up-with-a-good-icon-for-feature-x-should-i-ask-here-for-ideas).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) contains an icon called "ic_ab_back_holo_light.png" which looks the same as the icon from the design guidelines:

[image]

<sub>Located in ...android-sdk\platforms\android-14\data\res\drawable-xhdpi</sub>

Comment: And the filename is a misnomer, the affordance is known as Up, and it is behaviorally different from the system BACK button.

Comment: @RomanNurik files like this often get internal names before formal names are introduced, probably what happened here. Though they should have known better from the start; there's already a Back button on every android phone of course.

Comment: @BenBrocka, yep exactly!